# Backgrounding technique in iOS 7 for database update

Tags: ios, sqlite, background-process

My application at first Downloads a potentially large file and then reading that file updates my sqlite database. My problem is that if my application is backgrounded in the middle of this proccess i either end up with a corrupted database or with missing data (because the update process is interrupted)

For the fisrt problem of downloading a large file i can use the

> Background transfer service technique

However, i have not found a solution for updating my local sqlite database with no interruptions, regardless my app is in the background or the foreground

Comment: Background tasks(ios 6) have a 5 minutes window to complete their job. Do you really think yours would need that much time ?

Comment: Actually in IOS 6 background tasks have a **10 minute** window not 5, to complete their job. However, i am asking for a solution for **IOS 7**

Comment: If a task is active for more than 5 minutes, on a mobile device, you are probably confusing your iPhone with a PC.

Comment: @Alex Obviously you are ignorant of commercial applications with hundreds of thousands of data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an suggestion that don't update the database in background but maybe the solution.

First you need a way to help you keep the name of files which is handled and updated your database.(Maybe you can keep its name in a plist file).

Then, You download files as normal in background, and as soon as your app come back to foreground, you traverse your downloaded files and get the file which is not handled, then start to update your database.

Comment: what if the update is interrupted in the middle of a large file?

Comment: @Loukas If it is interrupted, you will update it next circle until update is finished and you mark it as updated.

Comment: What you are suggesting is a workaround. I was looking for an out of the box solution that doesn't involve me changing my synchronization code and having to keep states and line numbers of my every insert or update i execute

Comment: KudoCC is actually correct, that's what the app lifecycle is all about on mobile device. If your task can require more than the 5 or 10 minutes allocated to background tasks, and you don't want to track the update state, what's your options ? Catching the last committed index isn't that difficult anyway, KudoCC's is a viable solution.